# Is there any way to send transactions to a bitcoin node via RPC avoiding its broadcasting to the network?

Tags: mempool

If you use `sendrawtransaction` RPC call it will be "sent unconditionally to all peers" as the help says.

But if you only want to fill a mempool with transactions programmatically, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that in Bitcoin Core today. Generally, the goal is for the mempool to be a prediction of what transactions may be mined next; that also implies letting other nodes know about things added to yours.

This functionality does exist internally however, as it's effectively used when loading the `mempool.dat` file from disk on startup. So it's probably not too hard to add such a feature if you're capable of developing it yourself.